# Excel Cell Text Not Displaying Into Next Blank Cell

Tags: excel

Normally when you type enough characters in cell A1, they display over the cell(s) to the right (B1, C1, etc.).
I had a workbook where this was the case, then suddenly I noticed that the text in A1 only displayed in A1 and no longer displayed over the cells to the right. Cells B1, C1, etc. were completely empty/deleted/cleared. I could find no cell formatting like wrap text or otherwise that would cause this.

Is there a setting, global or otherwise, that would cause or allow this behavior?

Merge cells sort of makes the text appear as desired, but it doesn't make sense that this is the best fix. The cells were never merged before, and don't need to be merged in a new workbook for the "normal" behavior to be seen.

Comment: Is it possible there is some content in the cells you expect the text to overflow into? Having a space or any other character will cut off the previous cell's content.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the culprit setting: Show Formulas (Formulas ribbon tab, Formula Auditing). The shortcut for this command is Ctrl+`. My backward single quote is right above my tab key, so I bet when I was Ctrl+tabbing between multiple spreadsheets I accidentally enabled Show Formulas. I was in the data-entry area of my workbook, so it took me a while to notice formulas were displayed instead of results.

Comment: That's an interesting observation. I'd like to not show formulas and still be able to hide overflow text. Is that possible?

Comment: I googled "hide overflow text excel" https://www.google.com/search?q=hide+overflow+text+excel and the first three results had several approaches for doing that. The discussions brought up potential problems or reasons you might want to pick one method over another, so you'll probably have to pick your poison. E.g., one suggested setting the horizontal alignment to Fill, which "works", but is technically a hack approach because you're actually repeating the contents of the selected cell until the cell is full. That will "misbehave" for you with short-text cells.

Comment: I ended up pre-filling adjacent columns with spaces to prevent overflow. It seems like a worthwhile option that MS should add (to hide overflow text - not just wrap/shrink-to-fit).

Comment: @buffer: I know I'm late to the party, but you could also fill the cells with ticks (`'`) instead of spaces - this will enable you to copy the cells in text format as empty cells (and not space characters).

Answer (score 8):

mark affected cell(s), press ctrl-1, second tab and you will find a checkbox for text wrap.

Comment: It was showed alignment as justify and center instead of general and bottom.

Answer (score 5):

You likely have a space or some other invisible character in the cell to the right of A1(B1 C1 etc) highlight all of the cells to the right of A1 and press *delete*.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but this actually was my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you activated the "line break" option in the format of cell A1 and fixed its height.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but managed to fix.  I'm using Excel from the Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010.  I went to "options" and in the "Advanced" tab under "Display options for this workbook" and unchecked "show formula in cells instead of their calculated results".  Then the text started showing up in the adjacent cells.  For other versions of Excel as well this might work but you just need to find out where this option is. Hope this helps.
- Nelson

Answer (score 0):

An old question but still around.

Just had the same thing in office 2013. In Column A,125 I added a comment which appeared as left justified. I wanted it right justified to match the text above so, I re-justified all of column A.  I noticed (much) later that comments that had stretched across A, B, C, D & D 225 were truncated, with only the last part of the text visible. I did not want the text to wrap in the cell, but to overflow as before.
After much scratching about, the entry into the left column has to be Left justified, not right. 
As there are no columns to the left of A, only the last bit appears. Too simple really!